# How to communicate between my model and flex component?

Tags: actionscript-3, model, flex4, components

I'm trying to get my Actionscript 3.0 model that links to an SQLite database using Probertson's [SQLRunner](http://probertson.com/projects/air-sqlite/) class to talk to my flex component; I'm really unsure of how best to accomplish this. I have worked off a few examples, but I don't know the simplest way to tell my component the results of the SQL query.  Anyone have any recommendations?

Here is some of the code, to give you an idea of what I'm working with right now.

#### Component

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <model:Patient id="editedPatient" FirstName="{FirstName.text}" /> 
</fx:Declarations>  

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        /*imports*/
        protected var _patient:Patient;

        public function get patient():Patient
        {
            return _patient;
        }

        [Bindable]
        public function set patient(value:Patient):void
        {
            _patient = value;
        }

        private function creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void{
            _patient.getPatient(currentUser);
        }

        protected function save_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            _patient.update(editedPatient);
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:TextInput id="FirstName" text="{patient.FirstName}" />
<s:Button id="save" label="save" click="save_clickHandler(event)" />
```

#### Model

```
    public function getPatient(PatientId:int):void {
        var stmt:String = new String();

        stmt = "SELECT * FROM Patient WHERE PatientID= @PatiendId;";
        sqlRunner.execute(stmt, {PatientId:PatientId}, loadPatient_result, Patient);

    }

    private function loadPatient_result(result:SQLResult):void
    {
        if (result.data != null && result.data.length > 0)
        {
            var Patient:Patient = result.data[0];
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few things you can do...

First, I would create a [Model that follows the Singleton pattern](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/flex-actionscript-singleton-model-class) so you can bind to any data changes in any view, or component.

Second, I would then update that singleton'd model with in the **loadPatient_result** method you call.

If you want to de-couple from the result and the component, you could [dispatch a custom event manually](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=createevents_3.html) that contains the patient record, have the component listen for that kind of event and update itself accordingly. Or have that view listen for that event and update accordingly really.

You're on the right track. I think Singleton is what you need.

Comment: so just to doublecheck... if the code in my 'model' is singleton.. I basically add property assignments in the loadPatient_result method, and then use getInstances in the component that get an instance once the loadresult dispatches a complete event ?

Comment: If your model is a singleton, then you can access that singleton / model anywhere, which is awesome. i.e. using that getInstance() method to access the properties, save the data there or retrieve it. If the properties in the model are also [Bindable] then whenever they change, their values will be reflected in any components you have bound to those values!